# filter/search function in meteor

Tags: search, filter, meteor, publish

I'm looking to implement a search/filter function. It will use a drop down bar as its inputs (so we the user chooses from a set of options).

How my system works now is this: There is a Meteor.users collection, and an Instruments collection. Basically, each user has a list of instruments he plays (for example, Bob plays piano and violin, Alice plays the piano and the flute). In this case, there are 4 objects in the Instruments collection:

1) type: Piano
   owner: (bob's ID)

2) type: Violin
   owner: (bob's ID)

3) type: Piano
   owner: (Alice's ID)

4) type: Flute
   owner: (Alice's ID)

So what I'm trying to do is, when I choose "piano" on my drop down list, and then click search, I want it to display Bob and Alice's profiles. I guess this should be done using Meteor's publish feature, but just not sure how to do it (I'm a beginner here).

For example, if how do I tell that specific publication to run when I hit search? I see examples of people setting publish rules to only publish the subset they are searching for, but how do we tell it when to happen? Do we use another template for that so that when we click "search", the URL path changes and thus a different template?

To be clear, my question is just how should I go about doing this. Thanks!

Comment: The first question is how large is your dataset? If you have only a small number of documents, you could just publish all of them and change the selector for the ones that are displayed.

Comment: Would this be done using a helper? What if the data set is larger?

Comment: See the Meteor Parties example: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/master/examples/parties. It shows what users are attending which parties, which is only semantically different from showing what users are playing which instruments.

Answer (score 2):

To make it easy, try to bind the instrument ID in Person's Collection as Array,

```
[{
_id: 'BoBId',
Instrumets: [PianoId, ViolinId],
},{
_id: 'AliceId',
Instrumets: [PianoId, ViolinId],
}];
```

now you could find any profile, who has the instruments

```
Person.find({
  Instruments:{
     $in:[InstrumentsId]
  }
});
```